# Reload grid after add a new row in jQgrid Inline edit using inlineNav

Tags: jqgrid

I have been using inlineNav method for inline add as follows.

```
jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#mygrid_pager1",{"addParams":{"position":"last","addRowParams":{"keys":true}}});
```

It works great. Now, I need to reload the grid after adding a new row. I've tried the following and it didn't work.

```
jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#mygrid_pager1",{"addParams":{"position":"last","addRowParams":{"keys":true, "successfunc":"function(id){$("mygrid").trigger("reloadGrid");"}}});
```

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the value of `successfunc` should be the function and not the string (see in your current code `"successfunc":"..."`)

I would recommend you to try to add the same settings to both `addParams.addRowParams` and to `editParams` options of `inlineNav`. Moreover I would recommend you to place `$(this).trigger("reloadGrid")` from `successfunc` inside of `setTimeout` to be sure that reloading will be started *after* the standard processing of saving of the row.

So the code could be about the following:

```js
var editOptions = {
        keys: true,
        successfunc: function () {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 50);
        }
    };

$("#mygrid").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#mygrid_pager1", {
    addParams: {
        position: "last",
        addRowParams: editOptions
    },
    editParams: editOptions
});
```

Comment: I'm gonna give it try. Thanks, Oleg. I've also tried reloadAfterSubmit and set it to true, and I wonder why that didn't work neither.

Comment: @ToadyMores: You are welcome! Do you set `reloadAfterSubmit` only for add or for both add and edit operations? The problem is that "Save" button of inlineNav don't distinguish the options good enough and can use edit options (`editParams`) even you added new row. Some from the bugs are already fixed in the code of jqGrid on github.

Comment: You are right, I made a silly mistaken by surrounding the function with quotes. Once the quotes are moved, it works! I added setTimeout as well based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is after you finish add something, call reload function separately  like `jQuery("#myGrid").reload();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```